# Include second source file in Chapel file

Tags: chapel

In C++, when I need classes in 'actions.cpp' from `classes.cpp` I include the header, like `#include <classes.h>`.  But trying `use classes.chpl` fails, is there a `.h` equivalent I should be using?

Comment: Chapel intentionally does not have header files in order to avoid the user overhead of keeping two sets of declarations in sync with one another.  On the day that we find ourselves needing something like header files for separate compilation, we expect to have the compiler generate such files rather than requiring users to maintain them manually.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use is only for module names, not full file names.  If your file `classes.chpl` does not have an explicit module enclosing its entire contents, then you would type

```
use classes;
```

in order to access its contents from another file.

If `classes.chpl` is in the same directory as the file with the use statement, that should be all that is necessary to access its symbols.

If `classes.chpl` is in a different directory, you would additionally need to specify its location at compile time via the `-M` or `--module-dir` flag.  For example, if `usesClasses.chpl` has a use of `classes.chpl`, and `classes.chpl` lived in a directory named `helpers`, you would write

```
chpl -M helpers/ usesClasses.chpl
```

when compiling the program

Comment: At times, we have discussed adding support for some sort of `include` statement in Chapel that would be similar to a `#include` directive in C or `\input` in LaTeX.  This would support breaking a single logical module into multiple distinct files. However, that feature has not yet been implemented and doesn't relate to `.h` vs. `.c` (interface vs. implementation) considerations.  Think of it more as a means of splitting a code across multiple files for management purposes without the need to split it into multiple modules.