# Disambiguate source files in Chapel build

Tags: chapel

Following up on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47360626/include-second-source-file-in-chapel-file/47360888#47360888) about including source files.  I am including a Chapel modules that contains one file called `classes.chpl`, but my current project also has a `classes.chpl`.  What is the correct disambiguation pattern?  When I do

```
chpl -M/path/src
```

it notes the conflict, then chooses the `classes.chpl` in the current directory.  Should I compile the module for export as in [this page](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/master/technotes/libraries.html) or is there another pattern.

== UPDATE ==

The directory structure looks like

```
projA/alpha.chpl
     /classes.chpl

projB/beta.chpl
     /classes.chpl
```

Where each project depends on the classes in the respective `classes.chpl` file.  Trying to compile `projA` I am currently using

```
chpl alpha.chpl -M../projB/
```

But this causes a conflict, as it tries to use `projA/classes.cphl` for the classes in both `beta.chpl` and `alpha.chpl`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As described in the [module search paths](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/latest/technotes/module_search.html) tech note, the Chapel compiler searches for user modules by, in this order:

1. Looking at `.chpl` files specified on the command line
2. Looking at other `.chpl` files in the directories containing the files specified on the command line
3. Looking at `.chpl` files in the paths specified via the `-M` option or the `CHPL_MODULE_PATH` environment variable

Since the compiler finds the `classes.chpl` from the project directory using rule 2, and only finds the `/path/src/classes.chpl` with rule 3, it chooses the one in the project directory.  To get it to choose `/path/src/classes.chpl` instead, you can specify it on the command line so it is found with rule 1.

`chpl mainModule.chpl /path/src/classes.chpl`

Comment: I have been including them using the -M command, is that not correct?

Comment: In this case, -M is not sufficient since you need to disambiguate the 2 different classes.chpl that are found in the module search path.

Comment: In short, I need both `classes.chpl` to serve their individual projects.